# Constructing a non-copyable, non-movable type into a function parameter without invoking initializer_list constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

namespace {

class C {
public:
    C(C const &) = delete;
    C(C &&) = delete;
    C(int) {
        std::cout << "int\n";
    }
    C(std::initializer_list<int>) {
        std::cout << "initializer\n";
    }
};

void f(C) {
}

// Compiles and prints "initializer" when called
C g() { return {0}; }
// Fails to compile
// C h() { return 0; }

}   // namespace

int main() {
    // Compiles and prints "initializer"
    f({0});
    // Fails to compile
    // f(0);
}
```

Is it possible to construct C, a non-copyable, non-movable type, into a function parameter or function return value without invoking the initializer_list constructor?

Comment: I can't see a way to do that (this is also a problem with in-class initializers: `struct A { std::vector<int> x{2}; }`. You can't initialize `x` to have size `2`. And can't say `= 2` because the constructor is explicit).

Comment: You´re passing a copy of the object of a non-copyable etc. type. Why? Makes no sense

Comment: @deviantfan: I am trying to construct the object directly in place.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, can't you just say `struct A { vector<int> x = vector<int>(2); };`?  I can't test it right now because GCC 4.6 doesn't have support for in-class initializers.

Comment: @DavidStone, I don't believe you can.  If an `initializer_list` constructor matches in brace-initialization, it takes precedence over non-`initializer_list` constructors, and I can't think of a way to make the brace initializer match the `int` constructor, but not the `initializer_list`.  All other ways I can think of to construct a `C` will involve a (nominal) temporary when passed to or returned from a function, and that isn't compatible with a non-copyable, non-movable class.

Comment: @AdamH.Peterson without copying not possible, I mean. Perhaps `std::vector` wasn't such a good example.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb, technically that would be with a (likely elided) move, not a copy.  But, yes, the same problem would probably surface with a noncopyable, nonmovable type that had an `initializer_list` constructor that overloaded with a positional constructor.  (I think that's probably going to be an uncommon scenario, though, since immobile classes are usually resources, such as mutexes, and they don't tend to have `initializer_list` constructors.  But when it happens, you'll have to use the constructor's initialization list and/or delegating constructors instead.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's only possible if you can change `C` so the desired constructor can be chosen instead of the initializer-list constructor, e.g. by wrapping the argument type in something that isn't convertible to the element type of the initializer-list constructor:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>

namespace {

template<class T>
struct wrap
{
  T value;
};

class C {
public:
    C(C const &) = delete;
    C(C &&) = delete;
    C(wrap<int>) {
        std::cout << "int\n";
    }
    C(std::initializer_list<int>) {
        std::cout << "initializer\n";
    }
};

void f(C) {
}

// Compiles and prints "int" when called
C g() { return {wrap<int>{0}}; }

}   // namespace

int main() {
    // Compiles and prints "int"
    f({wrap<int>{0}});
    g();
}
```

This prints:

```
int
int
```